# i can't post from python to my wordpress site by wordpress_xmlrpc i get ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 222

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc

I can't post  from python to my wordpress site by wordpress_xmlrpc I get ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 222

when I am trying to run this code

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import GetUserInfo

wp = Client('http://mysite.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username', 'password')
```

I got this error ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 222

Answer (score 1):

I was replying to you on [GitHub](https://github.com/maxcutler/python-wordpress-xmlrpc/issues/123), and I figured it would be better for the other subscribers if we moved this off GitHub since it appears to be a WordPress issue.

Per Max, this appears to be specific to your WordPress sites. Since we don't have access to your websites, we can't tell you specifically what's going on. Per our conversation, here are the usual troubleshooting tips:

> 1. Disable your plugins and swap to a default theme, then try to
>      connect
> 2. If it works then, reenable the theme & check
> 3. If it still works, reenable 1 plugin & check again.
> 4. Repeat step 3 for all of your plugins.

On GitHub, you mentioned that the issue persists even when you disable all your plugins. Have you tried swapping over to a default them (like WordPress 2017) and trying it again?

I know you don't want to post sensitive info about your website here, but can you let us know a few things?

- Your WordPress version
- The plugins on your site
- What theme you're using

Hopefully this can help us narrow down the issue.

Comment: can you tell me the python  code that i need  to test the site after the new changes that you asked

Comment: WordPress 4.9.8 
all plugins been deactivated 
i put the default theme https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/

Comment: Try to run that last line, the one that looks like "wp = Client(stuff)". Put in your website's URL, your username, and your password like normal.

Comment: i tried again 
>>> from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
>>> from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost
>>> from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.users import GetUserInfo
wp = Client('http://example.com/', 'myusername', 'mypassword')
the same error 
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 61

Comment: Just to check, are you trying to visit **example.com** or **http://www.example.com/xmlrpc.php**? The reason I ask is that your ExpatError is now at a different column (61) instead of 2222.

Comment: it give me  xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 222   with xmlrpc.php   and    (61)  without xmlrpc.php

Comment: if you can give me any contact method like email you can see the issue by teamviewer

Comment: That makes sense. We will definitely get an error if you don't talk to the XML RPC page. Did you also include the full web address? For example: http:// www . mysite . com / xmlrpc . php

Comment: That sounds great. My e-mail should be in my profile.

Comment: i sent you the details

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is that XMLRPC for Wordpress is returning the XML encoded as what Python calls "utf8-sig" instead of "utf8", and `xmlrpc.client.Transport` doesn't check for an initial BOM, which causes the failure.

I solved the issue monkeypatching `Transport.parse_response` as follows:

```py
from xmlrpc import client
from xmlrpc.client import GzipDecodedResponse

def parse_response_(self, response):
    # Monkeypatching of xmlrpc
    # xmlrpc.client -> Transport.parse_response doesn't check for starting BOM
    # Code lifted directly from xmlrpc.client except as noted

    # read response data from httpresponse, and parse it
    # Check for new http response object, otherwise it is a file object.
    if hasattr(response, 'getheader'):
        if response.getheader("Content-Encoding", "") == "gzip":
            stream = GzipDecodedResponse(response)
        else:
            stream = response
    else:
        stream = response

    p, u = self.getparser()

    start = True # added
    bom = b'\xef\xbb\xbf\xef\xbb\xbf' # added
    while 1:
        data = stream.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        if self.verbose:
            print("body:", repr(data))

        # start addition
        if start:
            if data.startswith(bom):
                data = data[len(bom):]
                start = False
        # end addition

        p.feed(data)

    if stream is not response:
        stream.close()
    p.close()

    return u.close()

client.Transport.parse_response = parse_response_
```